# How can I mark this line in HTML file to be ignored by sonar rules?

Tags: html, sonarqube

I have a scenario where there is an AEM template file and in this file, I have a single `<li>` element. In other words, I have a loop inside that generate a list of items.

```
<template data-sly-template.step>
    <li
        data-sly-use.localStep="MyAdapter"
        data-sly-test="${(wcmmode.edit && localStep.start) || !wcmmode.edit}"
```

But, the Sonar's rule [RSPEC-1093](https://rules.sonarsource.com/html/RSPEC-1093) is complaining that:

> `"<li>"` and `"<dt>"` item tags should be in `"<ul>"`, `"<ol>"` or `"<dl>"` container tags.

In this case, is not a bug, once that the `<ul>` is outside of the template. The output file is a well-generated HTML file with no errors.

I'm trying to use `NOSONAR` in html file. I have tried `<!-- NOSONAR -->` and `<!-- //NOSONAR -->`, but is not working.

**How can I mark this line in HTML file to be ignored by sonar rules?**

Comment: If it complains about lack of surrounding tags inside a `<template>` then that's a bug in your code analysis software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I checked the [SonarHTML](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-html) plugin source code and for my understanding you have to add `//NOSONAR` at the line which should be ignored. In your case it should be:

```
<template data-sly-template.step>
    <!-- //NOSONAR --><li
        data-sly-use.localStep="MyAdapter"
        data-sly-test="${(wcmmode.edit && localStep.start) || !wcmmode.edit}"
```

If you compress the source code then the solution is safe to use. If not, you have to be aware that all those `<!-- //NOSONAR -->` will be send to your client. It means that the resources usage will be bigger (for example network bandwidth - more bytes to send).

`//NOSONAR` is handled by `org.sonar.plugins.html.visitor.NoSonarScanner`:

- [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-html/blob/4181edb5eff5605bec82dc0aa15ecd70eaa5857f/sonar-html-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/html/visitor/NoSonarScanner.java#L52)
- [test class](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-html/blob/cda2f6bff96d9dc459d92db32199a91fb9a8e1b3/sonar-html-plugin/src/test/java/org/sonar/plugins/html/visitor/NoSonarScannerTest.java#L45)

Comment: Thanks @agabrys. It works. As a complement, to avoid `NOSONAR` in output. I made it as a HTL comment, like this: `<!--/* */-->`

Comment: //nosonar for HTL issues still needs to be implemented in https://github.com/wttech/AEM-Rules-for-SonarQube/issues/230